# How to add click functionality on Task Card in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am trying to call a function on click of task card on the Teams view page, how can I do that, I am referring to **Point - 6** in the **TeamView** image.

[TaskCard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pdd7.png)

[TeamView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A50Ah.png)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [`Supervisor.TaskCard` has an `onClick` property](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.20.0/Supervisor%25E2%2580%25A4TaskCard.html) that you can configure. You can configure properties via [`componentProps` in the configuration object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/configuration#configuration-object) or via the [defaultProps API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/configuration#react-defaultprops-api).

An example with the defaultProps API might look like this:

```js
flex.Supervisor.TaskCard.defaultProps.onClick = (task) => {
  console.log("TaskCard clicked!");
}
```

I've not tested the above, but it should give you the right idea.